# Unable to overwrite image in file path on android (React Native)

Tags: android, react-native, android-storage, node.js-fs, react-native-fs

I am unable to overwrite files when storing them on android's external storage.

I have tried both `react-native-fs` and `rn-fetch-blob` but they both have the same result.

I've tried looking for more permissions to add, but I have them all (Allow read and write). I have also tried to delete the file prior to writing the file, but I am unable to do this as well, it seems like nothing works how it should.

Here is my code where I attempt to writeFile, I wonder what could be wrong?

```
const takeSnapshot = () => {
  if (canvas.current) {
    const snapshot = canvas.current.makeImageSnapshot();
    const data = snapshot?.encodeToBase64(ImageFormat.JPEG, 100);
    if (data) {
      const fileName = 'skiaImgRef.jpg';
      var skiaPath = `file://${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/${fileName}`;

      // write the file
      RNFS.writeFile(skiaPath, data, 'base64')
        .then(success => {
          getMediaThumb(
            `file://${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/${fileName}`,
            0,
          );
          passOnImageSkia(
            `file://${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/${fileName}`,
          );
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err.message);
        });
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: @blackapps thank you, I edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: And who created that file to begin with? How do you know that there is a file?

Comment: The authenticated user creates the file. I know there is a file because it only works the first time (on a fresh app install). After that it is always the same image. @blackapps

Comment: If an app can create a file then it can rewrite it too. And delete. What are you doing?

Comment: Well, I take the image from the camera roll, then I pass it to react-native-skia. I take a snapshot of the canvas (as seen above) and then attempt to store that file in storage. Then on the next screen, I try to load this file from the storage but it always remains the same. It never gets overwritten. On IOS it overwrites as expected. @blackapps

Comment: Sorry, you speak abacadabra.

Comment: @blackapps I think i am being pretty clear, thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is Android is cashing them so if you add Date.now() to the file name "skiaImgRef${Date.now()}.jpg", and then when you want to update it, just delete the old one and replace it with the updated one.

Comment: Great, this pointed me into the right direction! My images were indeed caching. Thank you @Radjapa